# Удобно вызывать шаблонные классы

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Столкнулась с тем что неудобно прописывать шаблоны каждый раз в конструкторе класса. Пример

```
template<class T>
class A{
T &type_class;

public:
A(T &type_class_)
:type_class(type_class_)
{};
  
};
class B{};
class C{};

int main()
{
    B b;    
    A<B> a{b};
    std::vector<A<B>> ab;
    return 0;
}
```

получается если нужно создавать несколько классов А нужно обязательно прописывать в какому классу шаблона относится. Как можно доработать, не прописывая A несколько раз?

P.S знаю что можно использовать наследование, я хочу разобраться как можно удобно пользоваться шаблонами

Answer (score 3):

Если у Вас компилятор с поддержкой 17 стандарта и для компилятора очевиден тип, то он может сам вывести.

```
A<B> a{b};
```

можно записать вот так

```
A a{b};
```

и компилятор догадается.

А вот `std::vector<A<B>> ab;` - никак. компилятору не очевиден тип переменной ab без подсказки. Но если подсказать

```
std::vector ab{a,a,a};
```

или

```
std::vector ab{10,a};
```

то все у компилятора получится.